# Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression

Tags: .net, ado.net

I would like to know if there is a function to correctly escape string literals for filter expressions. e.g.:

```
DataTable.Select(String.Format("[name] = '{0}'", MyName))
```

If MyName contains ' or a number of other key characters an exception is generated. The [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) indicates that these charaters should be correctly escaped, however there is a bit of confusion on how this is to be done.

I have tried replacing ' with ' and also ['] as indicated in the documentation, however the query still fails.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, in my case i just want to check that any row exist with given name so i was used LINQ for this. `Data.AsEnumerable().Where(row => Convert.ToString(row["Name"]).ToLower().Equals(newName.ToLower())).Any()`

Answer (score 37):

Escape the single quote ' by doubling it to ''. Escape * % [ ] characters by wrapping in []. 
e.g.

```
private string EscapeLikeValue(string value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        char c = value[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case ']':
            case '[':
            case '%':
            case '*':
                sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]");
                break;
            case '\'':
                sb.Append("''");
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(c);
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public DataRow[] SearchTheDataTable(string searchText)
{ 
     return myDataTable.Select("someColumn LIKE '" 
                                 + EscapeLikeValue(searchText) + "'");
}
```

Thanks to [examples here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Comment: This is not working for me for strings containing brackets.  The string **"Images [Three-Up]"** is being found by the filter **"entryBlockName='Images [Three-Up]'"** and not the filter **"entryBlockName='Images [[]Three-Up[]]'"**

Comment: Ah. The escaping of brackets is **only** when the filter is a LIKE clause. Not when it's an = clause.

Answer (score 7):

If I replace ' with two single ' the query works.

Comment: That's not even DataTable specific, but rather the general way of doing it in SQL. :-)

Comment: Although I use parameterised queries, so don't come across the need for this in SQL. But I get you.

Comment: If you use parameterized queries you are on the safe side anyway, but a TableFilter is an in-memory subset of SQL, consisting of a WHERE clause that must conform to SQL syntax rules. It's just a string, so no parameters here. That's why this extra step must be taken.

Comment: I admit that i was hoping the answer to this question would be “the parameterized version of `DataTable.Select()` is…”, but seems that MS decided every programmer needs to reimplement value escaping themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /// <summary>
    /// <para>If a pattern in a LIKE clause contains any of these special characters * % [ ], those characters must be escaped in brackets [ ] like this [*], [%], [[] or []].</para>
    /// <para>If the pattern is not in a like clause then you can pass valueIsForLIKEcomparison = false to not escape brackets.</para>
    /// <para>Examples:</para>
    /// <para>- strFilter = "[Something] LIKE '%" + DataTableHelper.EscapeLikeValue(filterValue) + "%'";</para>
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/</para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterValue">LIKE filterValue. This should not be the entire filter string... just the part that is being compared.</param>
    /// <param name="valueIsForLIKEcomparison">Whether or not the filterValue is being used in a LIKE comparison.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string EscapeFilterValue(string filterValue, bool valueIsForLIKEcomparison = true)
    {
        string lb = "~~LeftBracket~~";
        string rb = "~~RightBracket~~";
        filterValue = filterValue.Replace("[", lb).Replace("]", rb).Replace("​*", "[*​]").Replace("%", "[%]").Replace("'", "''");
        if (valueIsForLIKEcomparison)
        {
            filterValue = filterValue.Replace(lb, "[[]").Replace(rb, "[]]");
        }
        else
        {
            filterValue = filterValue.Replace(lb, "[").Replace(rb, "]");
        }

        return filterValue;
    }
```

Comment: how is this safe? it appears to trade one vulnerability for a more obscure one.

Comment: What vulnerabilities are you talking about? If you mean passing user input into the function then just don't pass user input.

Comment: just sayin' as the main driver for this escaping is usually bobby tables-types of attacks. which would not apply in OP case unless you send it to an RDBMS. besides enforcing syntactical correctness of the composed statement, of course. the actual flaw is the use of "magic string constants" which by themselves are a valid input.

Comment: simply put: use the code of your answer as the input of the function you posted, and it will return an incorrect output :)

Comment: True, but that is why I picked something that would never be used in my system for any reason other than this. "~~LeftBracket~~". It is a hack but it worked for me.

Comment: yeah, that's a fallacy. perfectly ok for personal "proof of concepts", but not recommendable in a professional environment. thus I neither up- nor downvoted, let's leave it at that.