# Error "Missing operand after 'Bannon' operator" - what 'Bannon' operator is?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

Working on a C# console app,  I have a line:

```
rowsFound = tempUsers.Select("EmailAddress = '" + userData[2].ToString() + "'");
```

`rowsFound` is a `DataRow[]`, `tempUsers` is a `DataTable`, and `userData` is a `SqlDataReader`.  I had the wrong index for `userData` (it was 1) and I got this error:

```
System.Data.SyntaxErrorException was unhandled
   Message=Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Bannon' operator.
   Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.ExpressionParser.Parse()
   at System.Data.DataExpression..ctor(DataTable table, String expression, Type type)
   at System.Data.Select..ctor(DataTable table, String filterExpression, String sort, DataViewRowState recordStates)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Select(String filterExpression)
```

When I inserted the correct index (2), the error went away.

Any ideas on what a "Bannon operator" is?

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Is `userdata[1]` the user's last name? Is his name "O'Bannon"?

Comment: Ok, i'm an idiot.  `userData[1]` is a name, `userData[2]` is an email address.

corrected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That guy was probably called `O'Bannon` (= `userData[1]`), resulting in the following string:

```
EmailAddress = 'O'Bannon'
```

The following Stackoverflow question contains a guide on how to properly escape data used in `DataTable.Select`:

- [Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386122/correct-way-to-escape-characters-in-a-datatable-filter-expression)

With respect to single quotes, you just need to duplicate them: `'` -> `''`.

Comment: @ J. Steen: IMHO, SLaks deserve this great comment :)

Answer (score 8):

`userData[1].ToString()` was probably something like `Bobby' Bannon`

Comment: Ah yes, the infamous Bobby Tables... (added for comic relief, on request ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1302473.aspx). Bannon comes from the either `UserData[2].ToString()`