# issues with finding data with certain strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping

I am trying to make this work but have been unlucky it is giving me th following error

```
Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%testing : | / - “ ‘ & * # @%' is invalid.
```

This search works as long as it doesnt contain a string as the one above.. This is my code for the search

```
DataRow[] rows = GetAllItems.Select("Name like '%" + cleanedText + "%'");
```

I tried - Modified per cHaos (still errors though)

```
  string cleanedText =  SearchText.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("'", "''");
```

but no luck when i enter the following string in the search although i know it is in the data

```
testing : | / - “ ‘ & * # @%
```

Anyone has a nice suggestion

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a SQL database?

Comment: Ummm... what does this do? `sSearctText.Replace("\"", "\"")`?

Comment: You do realize that `.Replace("\"", "\"")` does nothing useful, right?  Same with all the other backslashed replacements -- you're replacing wacky chars with *the exact same char*.  You probably want `.Replace("\"", "\\\"")` and the like.

Comment: sSearchText is the original variable - cHao, i used that Replace("\"", "\"") and it actually fixed the issue of not finding items with " in it.. dunno why, but i see your point

Comment: @cHao & Mark I changed sSearctText.Replace("\"", "\"")?  to sSearctText.Replace("\"", "\\\"")?  and still the same error.

Comment: @Oded the data is retrieved from the database and passed to the DataTable, I am searching the Data Table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386122/correct-way-to-escape-characters-in-a-datatable-filter-expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both % and * can be used interchangeably for wildcard characters in the LIKE comparison.

As such you will need to enclose these characters in square brackets in your expression string like so:

`Name like '%testing : | / - “ ‘ & [*] # @%'`

See [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

From the above link:

> Wildcard Characters
>
> Both the * and % can be used interchangeably for wildcard characters
> in a LIKE comparison. If the string in a LIKE clause contains a * or
> %, those characters should be enclosed in brackets ([]). If a bracket
> is in the clause, each bracket character should be enclosed in
> brackets (for example [[] or []]).