# DataView RowFillter like operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataview

i am facing small issue in dataview rowfilter.
How to handle textbox empty value in dataview rowfilter.i am using OR operator in this filter.
Please help Guide me in this issue.so far i using below code.

```
Column1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtColumn1.Text) ? "" : "%" + txtColumn1.Text + "%";
Column2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtColumn2.Text) ? "" : "%" + txtColumn2.Text + "%";
Column3 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtColumn3.Text) ? "" : "%" + txtColumn3.Text + "%";

dataView.RowFilter = @"Column1 like '" + Column1 + "'" + "OR Column2 like '" + Column2 + "'" + "OR Column3 like '" + Column3 + "'";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below code snippet will help you to control filtering with empty values. Plase try and mark the answer if it useful

```
StringBuilder filter = new StringBuilder();
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)))
    filter.Append("Column1 Like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'");

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text)))
{
   if (filter.Length > 0) filter.Append(" OR ");
   filter.Append("Column2 Like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'");
}

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text)))
{
   if (filter.Length > 0) filter.Append(" OR ");
   filter.Append("Column3 Like '%" + textBox3.Text + "%'");
}

DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = filter.ToString();
```

Comment: i tried your code.but if i dont give textbox1 value it throwing exception like "Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Or' operator."}.how to handle this situation? if i give value to textbox3 only

Comment: Dillibabu, Please see my updated answer. It is working.. Please mark the answer if useful

Comment: text boxes will contain user input. this is not safe for scripting. for example, entering an apostrophe ' would break the syntax and cause an exception.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface This is to generate filter query for a dataview. The user has to write a validation logic as well. as per solid principle, there is no point mixing validation logic with filter logic

Comment: validation is not the same as enforcing safe-for-scripting rules. apostrophes are often [part of names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). other characters with a syntactic function may be valid contents of user input as well. admittedly on a dataview, there is less concern about an injection attack, but the code is still missing the [minimally necessary escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928226/1132334).