# Not like operator not work in DataView RowFilter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I searched the web and found the example at [DataView RowFillter like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313631/dataview-rowfillter-like-operator). I need to get away some data in vb.net. But it seems the filter didn't work. Would someone show me how to do it. The column name is TypeStr and I don't want to show any data with order in this column on the datagrid. 
Thanks in advance.

There is my code on VB.net

```
Dim dvRow As DataView
dvRow = New DataView(ds.Tables(0))           
dvRow.RowFilter = "TypeStr Not Like '%Order%'"
dgrd.DataSource = dvRow.Table().DefaultView
dgrd.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the DataView directly as the DataSource:

```
dgrd.DataSource = dvRow
```

Otherwise, your code worked for me.