# Filtering a datatable row with a query condition that contains special characters like prime(')

Tags: c#, datatable

I get an error when the query contains a prime. Example: Cote d'Ivoire. Please how can I resolve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBvTQ.png)

```
internal static string GetGridDatumID(string v)
{
    return GridTable.Select(string.Format("Name = '{0}'", v))[0][3].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataTable select method with single quote conflict C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663605/datatable-select-method-with-single-quote-conflict-c-sharp)

Comment: I've never heard of **prime** to describe a single quote.

Comment: @GeertBellekens https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)

Comment: Yes @T.kowshikYedida

Answer (score 0):

For filtering a single quote character, You have to escape it in your search criteria:

```
return GridTable.Select(string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", "''"))[0][3].ToString();
```

Full example:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

var aRow = dt.NewRow();
aRow["Id"] = 1;
aRow["Name"] = "Name1'111";
dt.Rows.Add(aRow);

aRow = dt.NewRow();
aRow["Id"] = 2;
aRow["Name"] = "Nam'e2'";
dt.Rows.Add(aRow);

aRow = dt.NewRow();
aRow["Id"] = 3;
aRow["Name"] = "Name3";
dt.Rows.Add(aRow);

var foundRows = dt.Select("Name like '%''%'");
```