# C# - passing string to a DataTable to select specific DataRow

Tags: c#, ado.net, visual-studio-2017

I have made a lot of attempts trying to figure out how to make it work, but still have no clue. After passing log into expression it gives me answer that  there is no user, but in database, specified user exists. I don't know what to do more, maybe comparison in expression is wrong? I'd be grateful for any help!

```
string log = txtLog.Text;
string pass = txtPass.Text;   
else if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(log)) && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass)))
        {
            string exp = "login = 'log'";

            DataRow[] rows = tab.Select(exp);
            if (rows.Count() < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No users!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow row = rows[0];
                Console.WriteLine("log: {0}, pass: {1}", row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: I believe you need to change the assignment from `string exp = "login = 'log'"` to `string exp = "login = '" + log + "'"`, if I get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the value of the variable `log`, not the literal `log` which is what you do here:

```
string exp = "login = 'log'";
```

Instead use a String.Format:

```
string exp = String.Format("login = '{0}'", log);
```

or use the [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) as offered in C# 6 and up

```
string exp = $"login = '{log}'";
```

as this will make your `exp` value look like this, if log contains `username`:

> login = 'username'

Keep in mind that if a user enters a `'` in your textbox `txtLog` the Select will fail. You might want to escape those special characters: [Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386122/correct-way-to-escape-characters-in-a-datatable-filter-expression)