# Datatable.Select() cannot filter a value contains "#"

Tags: vb.net, datatable.select

A Database has a data like these

OVS0001#R1

OVS0001#R2

OVS0001#R3

I try to filter by using Select() function .

```
       Datatable.Select(" ITEM_CODE='OVS0001#R1' ")
```

The error message shows like these

```
      The expression contains invalid date constant '#R1"'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to escape characters in a DataTable Filter Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386122/correct-way-to-escape-characters-in-a-datatable-filter-expression)

Comment: I try to replaced by two character( # to be ##). But It is not work because it see '#' to be date.

Comment: You can also use the DataView.Filter, e.g., `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ITEM_CODE LIKE '%OVS0001#R1%'"`. That doesn't require escaping chars (well, it doesn't need *more* escapes).

Comment: If I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928226/2967965) correctly, then it should be `"ITEM_CODE LIKE 'OVS0001[#]R1'"`.

Comment: @MatSnow The standard `'%...%'` is enough here.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem (with .net 4.5.2 or 4.7.2) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cqaD.gif

Comment: @Jimi Yes, but wouldn't that include also `XYZOVS0001#R1XYZ` for example?

Comment: @MatSnow  If that's a possible case, you can close it on the right then: `"ITEM_CODE LIKE '%OVS0001#R1'"`. Or all of it: `"ITEM_CODE LIKE 'OVS0001#R1'"`

Comment: @Jimi I mean, it's not the same as `=`. That would still include `XYZOVS0001#R1` for example, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MatSnow  IIRC, it would not.

Comment: @Jimi OK, I'll stop the discussion here and test it. ;-)